# Show that abs(p(x))=e^x has a solution

Tags: analysis

How could I show that $$|P(x)| = e^x$$
Has a real solution, whereas $P(x)$ is a polynomial not identically zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $P\ne0$, then $\lim\limits_{x\to\pm\infty}|P(x)|=\infty$, but $\lim\limits_{x\to-\infty}e^{x}=0$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}{e^x}-|P(x)|=\infty$. Now use the intermediate value theorem on $|P(x)|-e^x$.

Answer (score 1):

If $x$ is negative and large enough, the polynomial is more than 1 (or less than -1), so the left-hand side is more than the right-hand side.
If $x$ is positive and large enough ...